# Why did the alien invaders let Russell Casse go?

Tags: plot-explanation, independence-day

In ***Independence Day***, Vietnam vet & redneck crop duster pilot Russell Casse was supposedly abducted by the alien invaders in 1986. He ended up a crazy alien conspiracy nut, shunned by others, which lead to his drinking problem. In 1996, when the aliens publicly arrived en masse, he was arrested for public disturbance, but soon let go. The alien attack proved that he was likely telling the truth.

**But why would the aliens, having abducted him in 1986, have let him go?** They clearly have no compassion for humans, attempting to slaughter them wholesale. Did he escape, or is there a reason for returning him?

Comment: Well, he could *still* just be a nut.

Comment: Isn't that how alien abductions have worked up until now (or up until the invasion)? I've heard plenty of stories of people claiming they were abducted by aliens, and experimented on, and then left. There are movies ("The Fourth Kind") and TV shows ("The X-Files") about this.

Comment: @BrettFromLA but that's for aliens that don't plan to just eradicate the species. Like, why would you bother? Just vaporize or space them. It seem seems benevolent for no reason.

Comment: You're right. But "Independence Day" used a lot of our cultural myths (though that's the wrong word), including Roswell / Area 51. So I figured the movie was just using another thing everyone has heard of: people get abducted by aliens, experimented on, and returned.

Comment: could he have been abducted by a different race of aliens? perhaps he just couldn't tell the difference...

Answer (score 3):

Aliens abducted Russell Casse to do experiments in order to find weaknesses of humans. So, when their experiments were finished, they let him go. Of course, their target wasn't the only Russell Casse, but the entire human race. So, they wouldn't be bothered with one, because, as per aliens' behavior and motive depicted in the movie, according to their plan all humans will definitely die in their attack.

Since they can read the mind, they were all aware of most common things they wanted to know. Perhaps, they knew that no one believe such kind of things and this is true because in real life, some people claim that they saw UFO and alien things, but no one believe it.